# UIPanGestureRecognizer and touchesBegan not called

Tags: ios, objective-c

in my app i added QuickSVG (https://github.com/quickcue/QuickSVG) and connected it to `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but the method `panDetected` not called
i run recursively on all it subviews and set `userInteractionEnabled = YES`
and `bringSubviewToFront` but it didn't help
please help me , what could be the problem ?
(also `touchesBegan` not called on the QuickSVG view )

in MainViewController viewDidLoad :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"svgtest2" ofType:@"svg"]];

svg = [QuickSVG svgFromURL:url];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[svg.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

svg.delegate = self;

[self TryToFixRecursively:svg.view];
[self.view addSubview:svg.view];
```

Comment: Is it playing the video? Are you sure you set up svg.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES?

Comment: this was a tough one my svg image not include size so the view not get a size
ie svg.view.frame.size.width = 0.0
Although he was visible and i can see the image (very strange)
so when i set the frame of the view like this

svg.view.frame =  CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 400);

the event panDetected start firing

thanks every one (I reply in comment due i opened account in stackoverflow today and i don't have Enough reputation to answer the question but this is the correct answer)

Comment: I posted your answer. Maybe someone else will find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is
One svg image not include size so the view not get a size ie svg.view.frame.size.width = 0.0 Although he was visible and i can see the image (very strange) so when i set the frame of the view like this svg.view.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 400, 400); the event panDetected start firing thanks every one.